# switchDevice() error Failed to GetUserMedia "–" NotReadableError "– 0 –" Failed starting capture of a video track

Tags: agora.io

I am getting the following error in switchDevice()
What are the possible issues?
`Failed to GetUserMedia "–" NotReadableError "– 0 –" Failed starting capture of a video track`
This error may or may not occur

- I am calling getDevices every time to get the device ID
- The target browser is Mozilla / 5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit / 605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 13.0.5 Mobile / 15E148 Safari / 604.1
- SDK version 3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following advice

> Make sure that if you are switching cameras to stop any existing tracks.
>   Stop all tracks in an active stream before acquiring a new one.

I tried the following and solved

```
## OK
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(video: true,audio: true).then((mediaStream) =>
        mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop())
)
## NG
localStream.getVideoTrack().stop()
localStream.getAudioTrack().stop()
```